# How Do I Arrange My div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to create a website. I want to create some div tags so that they are arranged like this:

```
1    2

 5

3 4
```

with the 5 right in the middle of the other four.

so far I've been able to just get all 5 boxes inside of my main content div.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="nav">Content for  id "nav" Goes Here</div>
  <div id="maincontent">
    <div id="box5">Content for  id "box5" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box4">Content for  id "box4" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box3">Content for  id "box3" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box2">Content for  id "box2" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box1">Content for  id "box1" Goes Here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</div>
Content for  id "container" Goes Here</div>
```

what do I do to the divs to get my desired view?

Comment: display inline first two, and last two

Comment: you need some css... but i would also order them like 1,2,5,3,4... have you tried anything?

Comment: the best solution for this is using bootstrap. Let me know if you would like to add bootstrap so that we can have the easiest solution.

Comment: Bootstrap is just one of the many framwork available, not necessary the best. How do you know it suits his necessities?

Comment: @SridharGudimela: using Bootstrap is **NOT** the "best" solution, especially for just one little task! You don't use an entire framework to arrange 5 divs.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid I agree, but this guy has mentioned that he is a newbie and he is just learning. So having bootstrap in the course might help him as a package.

Comment: @SridharGudimela: I disagree again. How is a beginner going to further their CSS development skills by using a framework this early on?!! You don't even write CSS with a framework, you just use HTML structures and class names. Frameworks weren't developed for beginners, they were developed for speeding up production. Your advice is awful.

Comment: @eugensunic bless you forever

Comment: @smerny i tried different insertion points and floating and margins and i made a big mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example for you that is very basic, naturally you will have to adjust it to fit your page. Essentially display divs 1 and 2 inline, as well as 3 and 4. After that just add adjustments as necessary.

```
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="five">5</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four">4</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .one, .two{
   display: inline;
}

.five{
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.three, .four{
   display: inline;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/Maqbpg)

Answer (score 0):

Order them 1, 2, 5, 3, 4

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="nav">Content for  id "nav" Goes Here</div>
  <div id="maincontent">
    <div id="box5">Content for  id "box5" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box4">Content for  id "box4" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box3">Content for  id "box3" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box2">Content for  id "box2" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box1">Content for  id "box1" Goes Here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</div>
Content for  id "container" Goes Here</div>
```

then using css you can align them.

```
#box1, #box2 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%; (or whatever else you'd like)
}
#box1, #box3 { float:left; }
#box2, #box4 { float:right; }
```

now you have to fit 5 in the middle and make sure it's past 1 and 2.

```
#box5 {
    clear: both;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

and finally 3 and 4 after 5, very similar to 1 and 2's styling.

```
#box3, #box4 {
   clear: both;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50%; (or whatever else you'd like)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This schema should work:

HTML

```
 <div id="maincontent">
    <div id="box1" class="n_ln">Content for  id "box1" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box2" class="n_ln">Content for  id "box2" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box3" class="blck">Content for  id "box3" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box4" class="n_ln">Content for  id "box4" Goes Here</div>
    <div id="box5" class="n_ln">Content for  id "box5" Goes Here</div>
  </div>
```

for css:

```
.n_ln {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left
}
.blck {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%
}
div {
    text-align:center;
}
```

it gives you a very basical responsiveness too.

https://jsfiddle.net/9r361zrj/

Comment: Thank you! inline!! i was going crazy